# Creating global variables in React/ Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have an external library that I need to load in and be able to reference in my app. The library is not available on NPM so I can't just import it at the top of my app like I have done for my other plugins. After searching around for the best workaround for this it seems that creating a global variable in webpack is the best way to access this library however the limited documentation i've found online isn't very clear. Here's what i've done:

In my webpack.config file i've added the following line in:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    MarketingCloud: "../src/scripts/marketing-cloud-javascript-sdk/marketing_cloud",
}),
```

My understanding is that the line above would give me access to the function in this script because it is now defined as a global variable but when I try and include in one of my components onclick functions I get a MarketingCloud is not defined error message. if I change this to window.MarketingCloud it renders out the page but the onclick function gives me the sane bit defined error.

Im using the create-react-app boilerplate which uses webpack/ babel. If it helps, here are the contents of the file i'm trying to add, the import jquery at the top was added by me to remove some jquery is not defined errors:

```
import {$, jQuery} from 'jquery';

(function($) {
  window.MarketingCloud = {
    env:   {},
    wsse:  new Wsse(),

    /** Make the api request */
    /* callback should follow standard jQuery request format:
     *    function callback(data)
     */
    makeRequest: function (username, secret, method, params, endpoint, callback)
    {
        var headers = MarketingCloud.wsse.generateAuth(username, secret);
        var url = 'https://'+endpoint+'/admin/1.4/rest/?method='+method;
        $.ajax(url, {
            type:'POST',
            data: params,
            complete: callback,
            dataType: "json",
            headers: {
                'X-WSSE': headers['X-WSSE']
            }
        });
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: it should work, but you could theoretically change the code that you export the generated code you have here, and then you can import it everywhere you want it, and make it work with bundles, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to attach it to the window object - `export default MarketingCloud` instead. To quote the Webpack docs (emphasis mine):

> Automatically loads modules. Whenever the identifier is encountered as free variable in a module, the module is loaded automatically and **the identifier is filled with the exports of the loaded module** (of property in order to support named exports).

Comment: I added export default MarketingCloud at the bottom of the marketing_cloud file if that's what you mean but it still didn't work